# react-bootstrap row and columns positioning error

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

As I’m building a React project. I'm using **Row** & **Col** from '**react-bootstrap**' where a Row is divided into **Col lg='8'** & **Col lg='4'** respectively. Beyond just this basic thing, I added a constant file from where I'm fetching values using props. Once I’ve gotten all of my  values using props, I go ahead and use map function for displaying information in the browser.

Setup here is actually really straightforward. I actually have two columns out of which **Col lg='8'** I'm using to store all of my information returned from mapping function. And luckily, it's happening pretty fine. Once this is complete, I still have another **Col lg='4'** which I'm using in the same way as I did earlier before i.e. for displaying information in the browser but not by using any props or any mapping function. And again, this is also working pretty good.

Now here’s what I'm unable to resolve. As my    work of displaying information in the browser is going well till here but this poses some issues of shifting **Col lg='4'** top-right to **Col lg='8'**. Why? Obviously this means that there will be a bit/lot of a problematic drawback in my code.

Here’s what I have at this point:

src > Routes > Blog > Components > Blogs > Components > BlogContent > index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { UserOutlined, WechatOutlined, MinusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';


const BlogContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            
                    <Col lg='8'>
                        <img alt='' src={props.imgsrc} />
                        <a href='' className='BlogDate'><h3>{props.date}</h3><p>{props.month}</p></a>
                        <div className='BlogCntnt'>
                            <a href=''><h2>{props.heading}</h2></a>
                            <p>{props.paragraph}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>{<UserOutlined />}<span>{props.category}</span>{<MinusOutlined />}</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>{<WechatOutlined />}<span>{props.comment}</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    
                    
        
        </>
    )
}
export default BlogContent;
```

src > Routes > Blog > Components > Blogs > index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss'
import BlogContent from '../Blogs/Components/BlogContent/index'
import BlogMap from '../../../../Constant/BlogMap'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Images } from '../../../../Shared/Assets'
import ImagesIcon from '../../../../Components/Cells/ImagesIcon'
import { LeftOutlined, RightOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';


const LatestBlog = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className='BlogSection'>
             <div className='BlgCntnr'>
                <Row>
                {
                    BlogMap.map((val, ind) => {
                        return (
                            <BlogContent
                                key={ind}
                                imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                                date={val.date}
                                month={val.month}
                                heading={val.heading}
                                paragraph={val.paragraph}
                                category={val.category}
                                comment={val.comment}
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }
                <div className='NxtPrvBtn'>
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>{<LeftOutlined />}</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>{<RightOutlined />}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                <Col lg='4'>
                    
                        <div className='SideBar'>
                            <div className='SearchSection'>
                            <input type='text' value='Search Keyword'/>
                            <input type='button' value='Search'/>
                            </div>
                            <div className='CategorySection'>
                            <h2>Category</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Restaurant Food(37)</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Travel News(10)</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Modern Technology(03)</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Product(11)</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Inspiration(21)</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>Health Care(21)09</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className='PostSection'>
                            <h2>Recent Post</h2>
                            <div className='PostItem'>
                                <ImagesIcon src={Images.post_1_jpg}/>
                                <div className='PostBody'>
                                    <a href=''>From life was you fish...</a>
                                    <p>January 12, 2019</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='PostItem'>
                                <ImagesIcon src={Images.post_2_jpg}/>
                                <div className='PostBody'>
                                    <a href=''>The Amazing Hubble</a>
                                    <p>02 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='PostItem'>
                                <ImagesIcon src={Images.post_3_jpg}/>
                                <div className='PostBody'>
                                    <a href=''>Astronomy or Astrology</a>
                                    <p>03 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='PostItem'>
                                <ImagesIcon src={Images.post_4_jpg}/>
                                <div className='PostBody'>
                                    <a href=''>Asteroids telescope</a>
                                    <p>01 Hours Ago</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='TagSection'>
                            <h2>Tag Cloud</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>project</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>love</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>technology</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>travel</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>restaurant</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>life style</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>design</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''>illustration</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className='InstagramSection'>
                            <h2>Instagram Feeds</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_5}/></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_6}/></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_7}/></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_8}/></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_9}/></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href=''><ImagesIcon src={Images.xpost_10}/></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className='NewsLetterSection'>
                            <h2>NewsLetter</h2>
                            <div className='NewsLetterForm'>
                            <input type='text' value='Enter Email'/>
                            <input type='button' value='Subscribe'/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    
                </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default LatestBlog;
```

**.scss file**

```
.BlogSection{
    padding: 100px 0px;
.BlgCntnr{
    padding: 0px 40px;
   img{
       width: 100%;
   }
   .BlogDate{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 210px;
    left: 47px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #01ff56;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
       h3,p{
           margin: unset;
       }
       &:hover{
           color: #01ff56;
           background-color: unset;
       }
   }
   .BlogCntnt{
    box-shadow: 0 0 13px 3px #0000001c;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    a{
        h2{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #2d2d2d;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        &:hover{
            color: #01ff56;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
    p {
        font-family: "Chivo",sans-serif;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
    ul{
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        li{
            a{
                color: #999;
                float: left;
                text-decoration: none;
                .anticon.anticon-user{
                        svg{
                            position: relative;
                            left: 0px;
                            bottom: 4px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            font-size: 14px;
                        }
                    }
                    .anticon.anticon-wechat{
                        svg{
                            position: relative;
                            left: 0px;
                            bottom: 4px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            font-size: 14px;
                        }
                    }
                    .anticon.anticon-minus{
                        svg{
                            transform: rotate(270deg) translate(2px, 0px);
                            color: #000;
                            margin-left: 5px;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            font-size: 14px;
                        }
                    }
                    span{
                        font-size: 14px;
                    }
                    &:hover{
                            color: #01ff56;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .SideBar{
        .SearchSection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            input[type='text']{
                height: 50px;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #999;
                padding-left: 20px;
                border: 1px;
                border-color: #f0e9ff;
                width: 68%;
            }
            input[type='button']{
                background: #01ff56;
                border: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
                padding: 12px 25px;
                border-left: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
        .CategorySection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                color: #2d2d2d;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            }
            h2::after{
                content: "";
                display: block;
                padding-top: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
            }
            ul{
                li{
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
                    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
                    padding-bottom: 15px;
                    padding-top: 15px;
                    a{
                        font-family: "Chivo",serif;
                        color: #150303;
                        font-size: 18px;
                        line-height: 30px;
                        margin-bottom: 15px;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        line-height: 1.4;
                        &:hover{
                            color: #01ff56;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                    }
                }
                li:last-child{
                    border-bottom: none;
                    padding-bottom: unset;
                }
            }
        }
        .PostSection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                color: #2d2d2d;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            }
            h2::after{
                content: "";
                display: block;
                padding-top: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
            }
            .PostItem{
                display: flex;
                position: relative;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
                img{
                    height: 100% !important;
                }
                .PostBody{
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-self: center;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 5rem;
                    bottom: 17px;
                    a{
                        font-size: 20px;
                        line-height: 20px;
                        margin-bottom: 6px;
                        color: #2d2d2d;
                        font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
                        &:hover{
                            color: #01ff56;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                    }
                    p{
                        font-size: 14px;
                        line-height: 21px;
                        margin-bottom: 0;
                        font-family: "Chivo",sans-serif;
                        color: #150303;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        padding-top: 5px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .TagSection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                color: #2d2d2d;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            }
            h2::after{
                content: "";
                display: block;
                padding-top: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
            }
            ul{
                li{
                    display: inline-block;
                    list-style: none;
                    a{
                        display: inline-block;
                        border: 1px solid #eee;
                        background: #fff;
                        padding: 4px 20px;
                        margin-bottom: 10px;
                        margin-right: 10px;
                        color: #888;
                        font-size: 13px;
                        &:hover{
                            color: #fff;
                            background-color: #01ff56;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .InstagramSection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                color: #2d2d2d;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            }
            h2::after{
                content: "";
                display: block;
                padding-top: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
            }
            ul{
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                li{
                    float: left;
                    padding-right: 6px;
                    padding-left: 6px;
                    margin-bottom: 15px;
                    a{
                        img{
                            height: 100% !important;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .NewsLetterSection{
            background: #fbf9ff;
            padding: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                color: #2d2d2d;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
            }
            h2::after{
                content: "";
                display: block;
                padding-top: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
            }
            .NewsLetterForm{
               input[type='text']{
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #999;
                padding-left: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 1rem;
            }
            input[type='button']{
                color: #01ff56;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid;
                border-color: #01ff56;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: "Shippori Mincho",serif;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                padding: 10px 50px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                &:hover{
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #01ff56;
                }
                
            }
            }
        }
    }
    .NxtPrvBtn{
        margin-top: 80px;
        ul{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            list-style: none;
            li{
                a{
                    font-size: 14px;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-left: -1px;
                    line-height: 45px;
                    width: 45px;
                    height: 45px;
                    color: #8a8a8a;
                    border: 1px solid #f0e9ff;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    span{
                        svg{
                            position: relative;
                            bottom: 5px;
                        }
                    }
                    &:hover{
                        color: #01ff56;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I hope I'm clear with my query. Thanks.

Comment: Probably due to the fact that you are arbitrarily inserting a `<div className='NxtPrvBtn'>` into the `row` …

Comment: CBore, this is for pagination and this I want to put after end of <Col lg='8'>. This was about scope now Can you please tell me that has I placed it wrongly in .js file?

Comment: You can not just insert any arbitrary elements into a row, and expect it to work. _“and this I want to put after end of <Col lg='8'>”_ - if you want it to have 2/3 of the width, then put it _into_ the column. If you want it to go over the full with, then make it a new full-width column itself.